# How to wait for user imput and return value in Java?

Tags: java, swing, dialog, filechooser

I want to let my user choose an Icon from a list of icons and I'm on the edge of being done, but I was looking at **JFileChooser and JDialog** and I was wondering how they do things like :
chooser.showOpenDialog(); which returns JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION if approved
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(); which returns JOptionPane.YES_OPTION if accepted

I tried some weird stuff like Thread.sleep and a while() loop, but I knew it wasn't the correct way because I read their APIs and I couldn't see anything like that. Even tho I read it I'm still really confused as to what is causing ** everything to stop and wait for the user imput**. I think pseudocode as to what the logic is would be enough! All I want to do is something like JFileChooser and JDialog which returns a value but waits for the user imput.

Thanks :)

Comment: First of all, you should rely on the functionality of the API.  Use an appropriate event model to handle your requirements (like `ActionListener` on a `JButton`).  Dialogs work because they do some black magic which allows them to take control of the Event Dispatching. Part of the process is used to "halt" the code execution without completely blocking the EDT and part of it is to filter the events so that you can't focus other windows/controls. Having said all that, when dealing with UI's, you need to stop thinking in a procedural  way and think in a event driven way instead

Comment: *"All I want to do is something like JFileChooser and JDialog which returns a value but waits for the user imput"* - then use a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane`, since they already do what you want, why try and re-invent the wheel, axel, car, road and traffic system

Comment: Thank you a lot MadProgrammer :) I'll be working on that now!